# Why don't Target/LeaveOneOut Encoders work well for Regression Tasks?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression, categorical-data, encoding

In [this review of categorical encoding](https://towardsdatascience.com/smarter-ways-to-encode-categorical-data-for-machine-learning-part-1-of-3-6dca2f71b159), it states early on that

> For regression tasks, Target and LeaveOneOut probably won’t work well

and later repeats that Target/LeaveOneOut (Owen Zhang's approach) encoders are best suited for classification tasks.

I could not seem to find other sources to support this claim, and I was wondering, why wouldn't LeaveOneOut encoding be a valid approach for regression tasks? Is it because it then causes overfitting to certain features? But then, how would this be different from a classification task?